# What is the contract of a function or variable in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, contract

I am a newbie at TypeScript and after installing it successfully on my machine, I came across the sentence "Type annotations in TypeScript are lightweight ways to record the intended contract of the function or variable" in TypeScript's official documentation page.

What is the word *contract* explained in the context of a function or variable in TypeScript.

The example that I took a look at was:

```
function greeter(person: string){
   return "Hello, " + person;
}

var user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML=greeter(user);
```

Is it something to do with string annotation attached with the function variable person?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Here is the link to the official [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in the word contract in this context: just as you can expect your employer to pay your salary at the end of each month according to your contract, you can expect that the argument of `greeter` will be a string (however you can break this contract very easily)

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain, using example.
Here is the code:

```
function greeter(person: string){
   return "Hello, " + person;
}

var user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML=greeter(user);
```

we’ve gone from passing a string value into the greeter() function to passing a number value. True to JavaScript’s dynamic nature, it doesn’t care - it just goes ahead and converts it to a string in order to render it to the browser. TypeScript is also happy, since the number can be converted to a string.

Here’s the problem: that’s not what I intended to happen. I only ever intended for the greeter method to accept a string value, but JavaScript doesn’t let me express that intent. The only way I can ever guarantee that the parameter value is a string is to write code to check it at runtime in javascript.

Here’s where TypeScript "intended contract" plays. If I only ever want strings to be passed in, I can say so by explicitly saying that the value parameter is a string.